# Kotlin Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Unsolvable problem when I try to start my app. I'm using Room database and databinding.
I've located the problem to originate from my database class but cannot seem to find a solution for the problem

```
@Database(entities = [FietsItem::class, Merk::class], version = 5, exportSchema = false)
abstract class FietsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun fietsDao(): FietsDao
    abstract fun merkDao(): MerkDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var databaseInstance: FietsDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabaseInstance(mContext: Context): FietsDatabase =
            databaseInstance
                ?: synchronized(this){
                    databaseInstance
                        ?: buildDatabaseInstance(
                            mContext
                        ).also{
                            databaseInstance = it
                        }
                }

        private fun buildDatabaseInstance(mContext: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(mContext, FietsDatabase::class.java,
                DB_NAME
            )
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
    }
}

const val DB_NAME = "FietsVerkoop.db"
```

When I comment these lines it works:

```
abstract fun fietsDao(): FietsDao
abstract fun merkDao(): MerkDao
```

My dao classes:

```
@Dao
interface FietsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertFietsItem(data: FietsItem)

    /*@Query("SELECT * FROM fietsen")
    fun getAllRecords(): MutableLiveData<List<FietsItem>>*/
    @Query("SELECT * FROM fietsen")
    fun getAllRecords(): ArrayList<FietsItem>

    @Delete
    fun deleteFietsItem(fiets: FietsItem)

    @Update
    fun updateFietsItem(fiets: FietsItem)
}
@Dao
interface MerkDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertMerk(data: Merk)

    /*@Query("SELECT * FROM ${Merk.TABLE_NAME}")
    fun getAllRecords(): MutableLiveData<List<Merk>>*/
    @Query("SELECT * FROM merken")
    fun getAllRecords(): ArrayList<Merk>

    @Delete
    fun deleteMerk(merk: Merk)

    @Update
    fun updateMerk(merk: Merk)
}
```

My Entity classes:

```
@Entity(tableName = Merk.TABLE_NAME)
data class Merk (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "merkid")
    var MerkID:Int?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "merknaam")
    var MerkNaam: String?=null

    ){
        companion object{
            const val TABLE_NAME="merken"
            const val MERKID="merkid"
            const val MERKNAAM="merknaam"

        }
    }
@Entity(tableName = FietsItem.TABLE_NAME)
data class FietsItem(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fietsid")
    var FietsID:Int?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "merk")
    var Merk: Int?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name="type")
    val Type: String?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name="prijs")
    val Prijs: Double?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name="beschrijving")
    val Beschrijving: String?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(name="autonomie")
    val Autonomie: Int ?= null
){
    companion object{
        const val TABLE_NAME="fietsen"
        const val FIETSID="fietsid"
        //const val MERK = "merk"
        const val TYPE = "type"
        const val PRIJS = "prijs"
        const val BESCHRIJVING = "beschijving"
        const val AUTONOMIE = "autonomie"
    }
}
```

This is the --stacktrace output.

```
org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Exception while annotation processing

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStreams

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams
```

I've been staring at this problem for 4 days now, any help would be extremely useful and feel free to ask for more needed information and classes

**Edit 1**
Even more --stacktrace output

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:361)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:354)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:340)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:377)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.access$000(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker$1.run(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:260)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:171)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withoutProjectLock(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:547)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:524)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:507)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:158)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:50)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:53)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:217)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Exception while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStreams
    at androidx.room.parser.SqlParser$Companion.parse(SqlParser.kt:206)
    at androidx.room.processor.QueryMethodProcessor.process(QueryMethodProcessor.kt:60)
    at androidx.room.processor.DaoProcessor.process(DaoProcessor.kt:100)
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.doProcess(DatabaseProcessor.kt:105)
    at androidx.room.processor.DatabaseProcessor.process(DatabaseProcessor.kt:57)
    at androidx.room.RoomProcessor$DatabaseProcessingStep.process(RoomProcessor.kt:134)
    at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:330)
    at com.google.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:181)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:147)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:79)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams
    ... 46 more
```

**Edit 2**
My build.gradle (:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
android { compileSdkVersion 29 buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
defaultConfig { applicationId "com.android.fietsverkoop" minSdkVersion 26 targetSdkVersion 29 versionCode 1 versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" }
buildTypes { release { minifyEnabled false proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' } } dataBinding { enabled = true } packagingOptions { exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module' } //groovy configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force "org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5.3" resolutionStrategy.force "org.antlr:antlr4-tool:4.5.3" }
//kotlin DSL configurations.all { resolutionStrategy { force("org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5.3") force("org.antlr:antlr4-tool:4.5.3") } } compileOptions { sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 } kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString() }
kapt { generateStubs = true correctErrorTypes = true }
}
dependencies { implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0' implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0' implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3' implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0' implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0' implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0' implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0' implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0' implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0' testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1' androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
// Navigation implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$version_navigation" implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$version_navigation"
// BottomNavigationView implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
// Validation implementation 'com.afollestad:vvalidator:0.5.2' implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0' implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
// Room components implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion" kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion" implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion" androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion" implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1" //implementation "androidx.room:room-coroutines:2.1.0-alpha04"
//Bron codelabs
// Room Database with Rx
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5" implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.5" kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5" implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1' implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0' implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0' implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3' implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
// Lifecycle implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0" annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0" kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0" }
```

build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript { ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72' ext.version_navigation = "1.0.0" ext.gradleVersion = '3.6.3' repositories { maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } google() jcenter()
}
dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3' classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha05" classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version" // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong // in the individual module build.gradle files }
}
allprojects { repositories { maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } google() jcenter() maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}
ext { roomVersion = '2.2.5' archLifecycleVersion = '2.2.0' coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0' materialVersion = '1.1.0' coroutines = '1.3.4' }
task clean(type: Delete) { delete rootProject.buildDir }
configurations.all() { resolutionStrategy.force "org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5.3" resolutionStrategy.force "org.antlr:antlr4-tool:4.5.3" }
```

Comment: try project clean & build, also if this didn't work try checking the exact log where its causing the issue. probably due to Dao queries or functions return types will be the cause and usually in android studio logs you will get more info about where room is not able to build the query.

Comment: The clean & build didn't work. The problem with this whole thing is I don't get any real info on what causes the error and where it originates from.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It seems that I might have finally found an answer.
I removed the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` line and replaced all the `kapt` lines with `annotationProcessor`
This somehow bypasses the problem.
I'll wait to accept my own answer for a few days so I have time to keep testing.

**Update**
So after adding the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` line again (for data-binding) it just works now. It seems that I had to replace the `kapt` lines with `annotationProcessor` to fix it

Comment: Where in the file do i put "apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt" ?

Comment: @L.Blommers at the top of the build.gradle (Module: app) file

Comment: Use annotationProcessor prevents the project to generate Room related classes

Comment: you are the greate

Answer (score 2):

I'm still learning Android and Kotlin but I think the problem lies in the Database class. However, I'm not sure but hopefully it will help.

Try:

```kotlin
abstract val fietsDao: FietsDao
abstract val merkDao: MerkDao
```

Comment: I'm sad to tell you that this did not work. It's a nice try though.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I tried @Rocco solution + updated the Gradle plugin version.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the problem in App due to using both Data and View Binding.

**Before**

```
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

**Resolved**

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in web. It turned out, I was referencing a non-existent class at my `Instrospector` into the configurations class.

After running: `Gradle` in terminal, I noticed the class name came as this `symbol: class nonExistentClass`