# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'. >

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Getting this error when making a build on Android Studio

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Comment: Can you post your app-level `build.gradle` code here

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69069742/2462531

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same error I was using below code

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

I solved using dependency as below

```
def room_version = "2.4.1"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```

Comment: That was the trick for me! Thanks, Gayatri!

Answer (score 4):

Getting the same on the Apple M1 chip. Works on my intel. Very frustrating

Comment: Getting same. Any solution?

Comment: It seems that I might have finally found an answer. I removed the apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' line and replaced all the kapt lines with annotationProcessor This somehow bypasses the problem. I'll wait to accept my own answer for a few days so I have time to keep testing.

Update So after adding the apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' line again (for data-binding) it just works now. It seems that I had to replace the kapt lines with annotationProcessor to fix it

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem.

I was using `kapt` annotation processor. Replacing with `annotationProcessor` solved my issue.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63034316/14313644) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by room library as it happened to me before.
Usually android studio gives more info about what's causing the error, you can check the build log and click on the parent error and it will give a hint to fix the problem.

If you are using Room please share your dao and entities so we can help.

It can be caused by many reasons but you can get more info about it by look into the parent error of "Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'."

sometimes you have to scroll top to see the real failing build error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this may look like a complex error but I sorted it out by replacing "kapt" with "annotationProcessor" in the build.gradle dependencies