# java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for .IngredientDatabase. IngredientDatabase_Impl does not exist

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kapt

I am trying to interact with my application but am encountering the error in the title.

I have followed the answer on: [Kotlin Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995176/kotlin-execution-failed-for-task-appkaptdebugkotlin)

in using `annotationProcessor` instead of `kapt` to get rid of the error:

> Kotlin Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

But now I am faced with a new error:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.nutritionapp.database.IngredientDatabase. IngredientDatabase_Impl does not exist
> ```

My project level Gradle file is (My Gradle version is 6.0.1):

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
ext.kotlinVersion = '1.4.21'
ext.navigationVersion = "2.2.0"

repositories {
    google()
    //jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

and my app level Gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
.
.
.
 annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$2.2.0"

 implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$2.2.5"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$2.2.5"
```

I defined my database as such:

```
@Database(entities = [IngredientDataClassDTO::class, RecipeNotificationClassDTO::class, RecipeOfDayDTO::class], version = 8, exportSchema = false)
abstract class IngredientDatabase : RoomDatabase()
```

I do not think I am missing any annotation as my application was working fine before. It was only after adding a new table to my database that the

> Kotlin Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

error appeared, which I addressed using `annotationProcessing` instead of `kapt` but again this gives me the error in the title.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.